# Have a select menu select a value in another select menu with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to have a priority level dropdown menu change a value of another dropdown menu dynamically when the user selects an option. I am using Jquery Mobile and not sure how I would go about making this happen. Here is my HTML currently. So if I choose priority level Normal I would like it so select 48 Hours in the commETA and compETA select boxes. Thanks in advance for any help!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/Estimates.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
   <h1>MGK Electric CTA</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
         <form class="form-signin" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>">
          <h4 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center;">Please describe CTA Below</h4>
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Customer Name:</label>
          <input name="Customer_Name" id="Customer_Name" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus required="required"><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Priority Level:</label> 
            <select name="Priority" id="Priority" required="required">
             <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
             <option value="High">High</option>
             <option value="Severe">Severe</option>
             <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Project:</label>
          <input name="Project" id="Project" type="text" class="form-control"><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Communication:</label>
          <select name="commETA" id="commETA" required="required">
           <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="Today">Today</option>
             <option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option>
             <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
             <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Completion:</label>
          <select name="compETA" id="compETA" required="required">
           <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="Today">Today</option>
             <option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option>
             <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
             <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
             <option value="1 Month">1 Month</option>
             <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Description of Issue:</label>
          <textarea name="issue" id="issue" required="required"></textarea><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Unknowns About Issue:</label>
          <textarea name="unknowns" id="unknowns" required="required"></textarea><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">People Invoved in CTA:</label>
          <textarea name="people" id="people" required="required"></textarea>
          <br /><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="doform" value="doform">
          <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

          <div id="message"></div>
        </form>

     </div> 
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-form1", function() {
  $("select").each(function(idx) {
    $(this).change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      //$(this).children("option").removeAttr("selected").find("[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
      if($(this).attr("id") == "Priority")
        linkOptions(value);
    });
  });
});

function linkOptions(priority) {
  var cases = {
    "Severe": {
      "commETA": "Today",
      "compETA": "Today"
    },
    "Normal": {
      "commETA": "48 Hours",
      "compETA": "48 Hours"
    }
  };

  if (cases[priority]) {
    $.each(cases[priority], function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).val(value).trigger("change");
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-form1" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>MGK Electric CTA</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
      <form class="form-signin" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>">
        <h4 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center;">Please describe CTA Below</h4>
        <label for="Customer_Name">Customer Name:</label>
        <input name="Customer_Name" id="Customer_Name" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus required="required">
        <br>
        <label for="Priority">Priority Level:</label>
        <select name="Priority" id="Priority" required="required">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
          <option value="High">High</option>
          <option value="Severe">Severe</option>
          <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="Project">Project:</label>
        <input name="Project" id="Project" type="text" class="form-control">
        <br />
        <label for="commETA">Expected Time for Communication:</label>
        <select name="commETA" id="commETA" required="required">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Today">Today</option>
          <option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option>
          <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
          <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="compETA">Expected Time for Completion:</label>
        <select name="compETA" id="compETA" required="required">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Today">Today</option>
          <option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option>
          <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
          <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
          <option value="1 Month">1 Month</option>
          <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="issue">Description of Issue:</label>
        <textarea name="issue" id="issue" required="required"></textarea>
        <br>
        <label for="unknowns">Unknowns About Issue:</label>
        <textarea name="unknowns" id="unknowns" required="required"></textarea>
        <br>
        <label for="people">People Invoved in CTA:</label>
        <textarea name="people" id="people" required="required"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="doform" value="doform">
        <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <div id="message"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** as Omar said in a comment, `val()` should work just fine - the correct filter is `:selected`:

```
$("select").each(function(idx) {
  var selectedValue = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected").attr("value");
});
```

**EDIT2:** initial `selected` attribute

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. How would I go about adding multiple instances of priority levels to this. (i.e. If I selected Severe it should select today in the commETA and compETA?) Thanks again!

Comment: the cases object is already planned to be expandable with all different priority levels, but i'm not  sure to understand what you mean with "instances"...

Comment: Your example actually showed me how you did it. I was missing the , after the }. Thanks again deblocker!

Comment: `$(elm).val("value"); $(elm).selectmenu("refresh");` proper way to select dynamically.

Comment: Use `.val()`. it should work normally.