# Jquery Mobile Multiple Select Won't let me choose more then 2 options on Iphone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use the multiple select option in Jquery mobile and every time I try to pick multiple options it keeps unchecking the other options. Here is my code what am I missing? In google chrome it will not even let me pick more then 1 option. On the iphone I can choose 2 options. I have the data-native-menu="false" on the select.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/Estimates.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-form1", function() {
    $("select").each(function(idx) {
      $(this).change(function() {
         var value = $(this).val();
         $(this).children("option").removeAttr("selected");
         $(this).children("option[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
         if($(this).attr("id") == "Priority")
           linkOptions(value);
      });
    });
 });

 function linkOptions(priority) {
    var cases = {
      
   "Normal": {
         "commETA": "2 Days",
         "compETA": "1 Week"
      },
      "High": {
         "commETA": "Today",
         "compETA": "2 Days"
      },
   "Severe": {
         "commETA": "Today",
         "compETA": "Today"
      },
   "Emergency": {
         "commETA": "1 Hour",
         "compETA": "Today"
      }
    };

    if (cases[priority]) {
      $.each(cases[priority], function(key, value) {
         $("#" + key).val(value);
         $("#" + key).trigger("change");
      });
    }
 }
 </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-form1" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
   <h1>MGK Electric CTA</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="page-content1" data-theme="a">
         <form class="form-signin" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>">
          <h4 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center;">Please describe CTA Below</h4>
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Customer Name:</label>
          <input name="Customer_Name" id="Customer_Name" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus required="required"><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Priority Level:</label> 
            <select name="Priority" id="Priority" required>
             <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
             <option value="High">High</option>
             <option value="Severe">Severe</option>
             <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Project:</label>
          <input name="Project" id="Project" type="text" class="form-control"><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Communication:</label>
          <select name="commETA" id="commETA" required>
           <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="1 Hour">1 Hour</option>
             <option value="Today">Today</option>
             <option value="2 Days">2 Days</option>
             <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
             <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Completion:</label>
          <select name="compETA" id="compETA" required>
           <option value="">Please Select</option>
             <option value="Today">Today</option>
             <option value="2 Days">2 Days</option>
             <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
             <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
             <option value="1 Month">1 Month</option>
             <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
          </select><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Description of Issue:</label>
          <textarea name="issue" id="issue" required></textarea><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">Unknowns About Issue:</label>
          <textarea name="unknowns" id="unknowns" required></textarea><br />
          <label style="font-weight: bold;">People Involved in CTA:</label>
          <textarea name="people" id="people" required></textarea>
          <select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" name="notify" id="notify" data-iconpos="left">
          <option>Choose Employees</option>
          <?php
     $users = $pdo->query($sql);
      foreach ($users as $row) {
          print "<option value=\"". $row["Name"] ."\">".$row["Name"]."</option><br/>";
      }

     $users->execute();
    ?>
          </select>
          <br /><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="doform" value="doform">
          <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit CTA</button>

          <div id="message"></div>
        </form>

     </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    //<script type="text/javascript" src="login/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44567712/4845566) for iOS and let me know if it solves the issue in iOS. For multiple selects still need to be fixed.

Comment: Because you have a function attached to all `select` elements. `$("select").each(function(idx)....` it's better to give all `select` items a class and attach that function to them except for the multi-select one. This way you exclude multi-select. http://output.jsbin.com/lubuwifabu

Comment: Omar, when I updated my code to reflect your changes it is selecting the options all perfectly now, but my validation is telling me that I need to select an option when I do have one set. Also, if I removed the required the database is not getting the $_POST values that were set in the select drop downs. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkLordi: can you post a new question with all your new code?